# Subtract with more than 2 argument in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to read some formulas from MySQL table and run it in java using :

> mongoTemplate.aggregate()

Some formulas are subtract like (2-3-4) or divide like (8/7/6). I write mongoDB project code in java:

```
ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project()
            .andExpression(Formula).as("totalSum");
```

Formula is from MySQL. But, *.aggregate()* returns this error:

> failed: Expression $subtract takes exactly 2 arguments. 3 were passed in

I can not change MySQL table. Because it has more than 500 formulas. What should i do to subtract or divide more than 2 arguments using  *.aggregate()* ?

Other my code that may you needed:

```
 Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchStage, groupStage,projectStage);
 AggregationResults<CalculateAggregateDataView> calculateAggregateDataViews =
            mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, MyCollection ,
                    CalculateAggregateDataView.class);
```

Comment: projection seems to be correct. post aggregate code too

Comment: Do you mean that it's possible to subtract more than 2 argument in mongoDB? I test it using shell command and it returns same error.

Comment: But i think mongo should has features to calculate this formula. It's not acceptable to me that mongo can not does this work.

Comment: what's the value of `Formula`?. it must be string

Comment: Yes. That is String

Comment: you can eval `Formula` then send it to expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the docs [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract) can accept any [expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions) and you can nest expressions.

check this for mongo shell example:

suppose we have the following document in `collection`

```
{
  "value1":4,
  "value2":3,
  "value3":2
}
```

so we can do the following aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     {$addFields: {$subtract: [
           {$subtract: ["$value1","$value2"]}, //will serve as the first input for the outer $subtract
           "$value3"
     ]}
 ]);
```